# Angular Material Icon Button ripples but doesn't fire click

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm noticing that angular material icon buttons have some sort of margin around them where upon click the ripple effect does trigger, but the click handler doesn't.

I've reproduced this in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and Edge (haven't tested other browsers)

Example of the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgyutl

Is this a bug in @angular/material or am I doing something wrong? If so, is there any way to make sure the ripple never fires without also firing the  click handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the click event in the button element, not in the icon.
Change your template to:

```
<button (click)="showHelp($event)" mat-icon-button>
   <mat-icon>help_outline</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that, It really was that simple. Thanks!

Comment: this is the answer for me too.