# Angular Material click event doesn't fire

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wrote a shopping cart component using Angular Material, which shows a list of products and their respective quantities. However, when I click the controls associated with each item, the `(click)` binding doesn't get called. It appears as though some invisible element is intercepting the click and stopping it from reaching my components but I didn't manage to identify this element.

The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/roninbar/2021-05-03-angular-material-click) and on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-2nubjy?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216882/14945696

Comment: check this thread and comment: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/3478#issuecomment-289880649

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling a function in your `ngFor` that is returning the collection. Now every time the change detection runs, that function is executed and returns completely new objects. A click on the button is triggering the change detection.

As a consequence the object identity gets lost and Angular has to redraw the elements. This has the effect that the event handlers are not executed as they are supposed to.

Possible fixes:

1. trackBy: Use `*ngFor="let item of getAllItems(); trackBy: identify`. identify is a method of your component which will now verify the object identity. The identify method would lookup and return the unique id. This is done in https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-2nubjy-xozfck
2. Don't call `getAllItems()`. In your case that would be the better approach. Create a property `allItems` that you use in `ngFor` and let the event handlers change them. More clearer and also better performance: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-2nubjy-gosaa7

Comment: Great! Thanks! But what exactly did you change and how did it fix the problem?

Comment: Updated my original answer with a more detailed explanation. Is it clear now?

Comment: `trackBy` solves the problem. As for your 2nd suggestion, if I understand you correctly, what you're suggesting is that I keep two identical copies of the same data: one in local storage, as I'm doing now, and another one in the component. How is this better than `trackBy`?